# Relating a model on a foreign key

Tags: django

I have the following custom User model.  It has a field coid that i'd like to relate to my facility dimension table.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):



    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
    formattedusername = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, primary_key = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_cfo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    officename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    jobdescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    positioncode = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    positiondescription = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    coid = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    streetaddress = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = "user"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.formattedusername = '{domain}\{username}'.format(
            domain='HCA', username=self.username)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs);

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
```

I've defined the foreignkey in my Facility_Dimension table, but it's trying to create the relationship on formattedusername.

```
class FacilityDimension(models.Model):
    unit_num = models.CharField(db_column='Unit_Num', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    company_code = models.CharField(db_column='Company_Code', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    coid = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,db_column='Coid',primary_key=True, serialize=False, max_length=5)  # Field name made lowercase.
    coid_name = models.CharField(db_column='COID_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    c_level = models.CharField(db_column='C_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    company_name = models.CharField(db_column='Company_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    s_level = models.CharField(db_column='S_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sector_name = models.CharField(db_column='Sector_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    b_level = models.CharField(db_column='B_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    group_name = models.CharField(db_column='Group_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    r_level = models.CharField(db_column='R_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    division_name = models.CharField(db_column='Division_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    d_level = models.CharField(db_column='D_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    market_name = models.CharField(db_column='Market_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    f_level = models.CharField(db_column='F_Level', max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cons_facility_name = models.CharField(db_column='Cons_Facility_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lob_code = models.CharField(db_column='LOB_Code', max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lob_name = models.CharField(db_column='LOB_Name', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sub_lob_code = models.CharField(db_column='Sub_LOB_Code', max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sub_lob_name = models.CharField(db_column='Sub_LOB_Name', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    state_code = models.CharField(db_column='State_Code', max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_id_current = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_ID_Current', max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_current_name = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_Current_Name', max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_id_future = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_ID_Future', max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_future_name = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_Future_Name', max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_7_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_7_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_8_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_8_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_phys_svc_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Phys_Svc_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_asd_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_ASD_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_imaging_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Imaging_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_oncology_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Oncology_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_cath_lab_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Cath_Lab_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_intl_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Intl_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    summary_other_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='Summary_Other_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_coid = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_COID', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pas_status = models.CharField(db_column='PAS_Status', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    company_code_operations = models.CharField(db_column='Company_Code_Operations', max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    osg_pas_ind = models.CharField(db_column='OSG_PAS_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    abs_facility_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='ABS_Facility_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    abl_facility_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='ABL_Facility_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    intl_pmis_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='INTL_PMIS_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hsc_member_ind = models.CharField(db_column='HSC_Member_Ind', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    loaddate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='LoadDate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Facility_Dimension'
```

All my other tables relate to my User table by the formattedusername which is what I want, except for this model relationship.

I've tried adding the ForeignKey relationship in my User Model, but since it loads prior to the FacilityDimension it doesn't recognize my FacilityDimension table

I get the following error when using the following foreignkey when attempting to run makemigrations in my User model:

```
NameError: name 'FacilityDimension' is not defined

coid = models.ForeignKey(FacilityDimension,max_length=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by one of the following approaches:

1. import related model prior User class model
2. Stringfy Class name in [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) (used mostly if there are circular imports)

   `models.ForeignKey('myapp.FacilityDimension', max_length=5)`

Comment: If I import the model prior, then the relationship to User doesn't exist and we are left in the same boat.  I'll look into Stringy Class name.

Comment: googling stringy class django doesn't provide any information, could you provide an example?

Comment: The Django [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) docs show how to use a string. You can use `models.ForeignKey(Model)`, `models.ForeignKey('MyModel')` (if `MyModel` is in the same app), or `models.ForeignKey('myapp.MyModel')`.

Comment: @Alasdair I have already included example for him to see when I published answer but didn't bother to respond as he didn't bother to read code, if you are willing to edit my answer and add following resources to it I would gladly accept edit

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could use related_name = 'coid' in my model.  This solved the problem.